# How To fill a combobox with SortedList

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, sortedlist

I have, on my own created a SortedList, which I cannot bind to a combobox, I'm not doing it from XAML i'm doing it from the code:

```
 SortedList<int, string> AreaList = new SortedList<int, string>();
            AreaList.Add(1, "Agriculture");
            AreaList.Add(2, "Forestry");
            AreaList.Add(3, "Fruits");
            AreaList.Add(4, "Food");
            AreaList.Add(5, "Metals");
            AreaList.Add(6, "Mining");
            AreaList.Add(7, "Electricity");
            AreaList.Add(8, "Building Contracts");
            AreaList.Add(9, "Transport");
            AreaList.Add(10, "Alcohol");
            AreaList.Add(11, "Information Technologies");
            AreaList.Add(12, "Health And Social Services");
            AreaList.Add(13, "Art and Entertainement");
            AreaList.Add(14, "Hospitality Business");
            AreaList.Add(15, "Education");
            AreaList.Add(16, "Real Estate");
            AreaList.Add(17, "Sales");
            AreaList.Add(18, "Architecture");
            AreaList.Add(19, "Engineering");
            AreaList.Add(20, "Wholesale");

        comboBox1.ItemsSource = AreaList.ToList();
        comboBox1.SelectedValue = "TKey";
        comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "TValue";
```

i dont know what i'm doing wrong, its my first time with SortedLists, and I'm a begginer in WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need the `SortedList`, but at the end (due to `ToList()` call) you are actually binding to `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`, so you need to set [`SelectedValuePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows:

```
comboBox1.SelectedValuePath = "Key"; // bind to KeyValuePair<int, string>.Key property
comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";  // bind to KeyValuePair<int, string>.Value property
```

Comment: Well should i use just the regular List?
And with this it still gives me A System.NullReferenceException!
@IvanStoev

Comment: I don't know what gives you `NullReferenceException`. When I put the code you provided with my corrections, I'm getting a filled combo box.

Comment: I finally figure it out, i erased the InitializeComponent();
That is the reason it was giving me the exception! so you were right!
@IvanStoev